# Ember.js - Ember.Js View inside handlebars conditional: view not being displayed?

Tags: javascript, html, ember.js

I've got a [handlebars conditional statement](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/422/) in a table, and inside that I have a view.

If i [remove the conditional](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/423/) then the view template is displayed. If I [remove the view template](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/424/), the straight html is displayed. But if [both are there](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/422/), the view template is never shown, and there is no error shown in the console:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button {{action 'click_me'}}>Click me</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        {{#if controller.new_visible}}
            {{#view App.MyView}}
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        Hello!            
                    </td>
            </tr>
            {{/view}}
        {{/if}}
    </table>
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I like the way you described your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move your condition inside view. see this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PkT8x/426/)

```
{{#view App.MyView}}
{{#if controller.new_visible}}
<tr>
    <td>
        Hello!            
    </td>
</tr>
{{/if}}
{{/view}}
```

Comment: Ah - thank you - this works - but why? Why doesn't having the conditional on the outside work?

Comment: Frankly speaking i don't know either. I started searching for it. Once i got to know, I'll let you know. One thing with ember is you have to do all in prescribed way. Then only you can get bindings work correctly. But they prescribe lot of ways for same task.

Answer (score 2):

Further to this, it would seem (from http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/the-view-layer/, section 4) that Ember creates virtual views for Handlebars logic block helpers (like `{{#if}}`, `{{#unless}}`, and so on. They're not part of the regular view hierarchy, so they don't play nicely with regular nested child views.

I suspect the answer to this is to be found somewhere in this line:

"When the path passed to an `{{#if}}` or `{{#with}}` changes, Ember automatically re-renders the virtual view, which will replace its contents, and importantly, destroy all child views to free up their memory." (from the section linked above).

My best guess is that the `{{#if}}` block is re-rendering on insert, which destroys the 'child' `{{#view}}` block within it.